# Where can I find the Identifier of a computer to add as my friend in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I don't know how to add a new contact. I press add a new contact, but I don't know what to type in.

Thanks.

(My friend has a mac)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll want to do is determine what service you want to connect with. For example, your friend may have a gmail chat account, AIM account, AOL account, Facebook account. etc. You will also need an account with the same service as your friend.

Once you know what service you will be chatting through, you can select that in the window that pops up when you click add contact. It should be a menu list of various services.

The identifier is the name of the account for your friend, it's sort of like an email address. So for example, if you and your friend are going to connect via a gmail/google chat/XMPP service then his/her identifier might be his/her email address "something"@gmail.com. If you plan to use AIM accounts, then the identifier would be their AIM ID.

So first, determine the chat service you'll be using and then use the user account name as the identifier.

Hope that helps.